# Different style format in different browsers

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am using border style for a div element. I want to change the border style dynamically using jQuery.

When I get the border style in jQuery, sometimes in Chrome it works fine and sometimes not. In IE it doesn't work, in Mozilla it works fine.

Below is my code:

**// This is HTML element**

```
<div id="blankcontainer1" style="overflow:hidden; width:100px; 
                          height:100px; background-color:#a2a2a2; 
                          border-top-width:1px; 
                          border-top-style:solid; 
                          border-top-color:#fa0000; 
                          border-right:1px solid #666666; 
                          border-bottom:1px solid #666666; 
                          border-left:1px solid #666666; 
                          border-top-left-radius:0px; 
                          border-top-right-radius:0px; 
                          border-bottom-left-radius:0px; 
                          border-bottom-right-radius:0px;"></div>
```

**// This is Javascript**

```
var elestyle = $("#blankcontainer1").attr("style");
var splitstyle = elestyle.split(";");

var i = 0;
while(i < splitstyle.length){
    var attrstyle = splitstyle[i].split(":");
    if($.trim(attrstyle[0]) == "border-top-width")
        $("#containersetting #btsize").val($.trim(attrstyle[1]).substring(0, $.trim(attrstyle[1]).length-2));
    if($.trim(attrstyle[0]) == "border-top-style")
        $("#containersetting #btstyle").val($.trim(attrstyle[1]));
    if($.trim(attrstyle[0]) == "border-top-color"){
        var bordtcolor = $.trim(attrstyle[1]);
        if(bordtcolor.indexOf('rgb') !== -1)                 
                bordtcolor=colorToHex(bordtcolor);

        $("#containersetting #btcolor").val(bordtcolor);
    }
}
```

In the above code, Chrome style displayed -

```
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #fa0000;
```

But sometimes it displays

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(250, 0, 0) rgb(102, 102, 102) rgb(102, 102, 102);
```

IE style displayed:

```
border-top:#fa0000 1px solid;
```

So, this is caused by my JavaScript code failing. Can you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the style values using jQuery - like this:

```
var borderTopColor = $('#blankcontainer1').css('border-top-color');

alert(borderTopColor);
```

This means you don't need to try and manually parse the style attribute.

You can also [animate style changes](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), including [colours, with the jquery-color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color):

```
$('#blankcontainer1').animate({
    borderTopColor: '#abcdef'
}, 1000);
```

And finally... if you are doing this on something represented by a CSS psuedo-class (like `:hover`), you could use a CSS3 transition:

```
a {
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    borderTopColor: #fedcba;
}

a:hover {
    borderTopColor: #abcdef;
}
```